# Require certain attribute value if element has no content

Tags: xml, xsd

Suppose I have a type definition like so:

```
<xs:complexType name="title-type">                                            
  <xs:simpleContent>                                                          
    <xs:extension base="xs:string">                                          
      <xs:attribute name="hide" type="xs:boolean" default="false" />          
    </xs:extension>                                                           
  </xs:simpleContent>                                                         
</xs:complexType>
```

This allows for empty content, which is fine. However, I would like to require that *if* the content is empty then the attribute `hide="true"`.

How do I do that?

Comment: Can you use XSD 1.1?

Comment: Maybe the xs:nillable attribute is what you need instead ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot express your constraint in XSD 1.0, but you can using `xs:assert` in XSD 1.1.

### XSD 1.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
  vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:complexType name="title-type">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="hide" type="xs:boolean" default="false" />
        <xs:assert test=". != '' or @hide = true()"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="title" type="title-type"/>
</xs:schema>
```